# "ERROR" displayed on head items

Tags: team-fortress-2

In game, instead of hats (any other than default) a big 3D red "ERROR" is displayed. It used to work well till the update (the one when everyone got that paper boat hat). After loading a character's hat (in menu or in game no difference), the game would crash, and after few more updates I'm stuck with the "ERROR hat".

Anyone else got this, are there any fixes or updates planned?

*NOTE*: I didn't use any mods, touch Steam files or other things that would result in missing data.

[Screenshot](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/648743187034583989/094EA502C30485DCFB523507756B7E56B838C3FB/)

Comment: Have you had Steam verify the file integrity for your TF2 install?

Comment: Didn't know about that,i tried it now but it's still the same.Reinstalling the game completly  should work but it is the last option...btw what does "defragment cache" on stem do? is it worth running?

Comment: checking file integrity is effectively the same as a reinstall (except you keep your settings) - any file that isn't "right" would have been automatically re-downloaded. Defrag'ing the cache will simply defrag all the games downloaded files, only useful if they're heavily fragmented, but otherwise no effect.

Comment: If you have the developer console enabled, what errors are appearing in it?  You can enable it via Options -> Advanced -> Enable Developer Console, then press the key left of 1 on the kwyboard (` or ~ for US 104/105) to open it.

Comment: It works now,the "verify integrity" worked but the changes took effect only after I restarted steam client.Post as an answer if you want accept.

Comment: @DMA57361: I'm doing this just to ping you so you can see Arremer's comment right before mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot I'd say that looks like the model is missing or corrupt.

First thing to do in this case is verify your TF2 file cache, this will check your TF2 install is up to date and no files are corrupt or missing - and download anything it needs to make your game correct.

Go to the game's properties from the Steam Library and you'll find a **"Verify Integrity of Game Cache..."** button, hit that and let it check for anything broken and re-download it (this may take some time depending on how much has to be redownloaded). You might need to re-start Steam before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Or reinstall Team Fortress 2 that had an update in this year because the
game has new Steam Workshop hats. Even guns and melee weapons too.
That is how you install the hats again.
Re-install if the game is up to date if the Steam Workshop Hats, Weapons and Melee Weapons where never installed when they confirmed them.